# Why doesn't the keylistener work?

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I'm trying to run a code I wrote for a moving ball (sorry if the code is messy... i'm not very experienced... ) it doesn't show any error messages but when I click at the appletviewer and press the keys, the ball doesn't change it's direction. Why does that happen?
p.s. I'm using "eclipse" for writing my codes is it a good compiler? maybe the problem is there?

```
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Main extends Applet implements KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    boolean right=true;
    boolean left=false;
    boolean up=false;
    boolean down=false;
    boolean inGame=true;

    public void listen(){
        addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        left=true;
        up=false;
        down=false;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        right=true;
        up=false;
        down=false;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        up=true;
        right=false;
        left=false;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        down=true;
        right=false;
        left=false;
    }

}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
    int x1=5;
    int y1=5;
    int x2=x1+5;
    int y2=y1+5;    

    public int moveRight(){
        return ++x1;
    }

    public int moveLeft(){
        return --x1;
    }

    public int moveUp(){
        return ++y1;
    }

    public int moveDown(){
        return --y1;
    }

    public void paint1(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics e){
        long millis =System.currentTimeMillis();
        long millisn =System.currentTimeMillis();           
        while (right=true){
            millis =System.currentTimeMillis();
            millisn =System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (millisn<millis+20){
                millisn=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }    
        e.setColor(Color.white);
        e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        e.setColor(Color.red);
        moveRight();
        e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
        }
        while(inGame==true){
            if(right==true){                    
                millis =System.currentTimeMillis();
                millisn =System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (millisn<millis+20){
                        millisn=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }    
                e.setColor(Color.white);
                e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                e.setColor(Color.red);
                moveRight();
                e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                listen();
            }    
            else if(down==true){
                    millis =System.currentTimeMillis();
                    millisn =System.currentTimeMillis();                        
                        while (millisn<millis+20){
                                    millisn=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }    
                    e.setColor(Color.white);
                    e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                    e.setColor(Color.red);
                    moveDown();
                    e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            }
                else if (left==true){
                    millis =System.currentTimeMillis();
                    millisn =System.currentTimeMillis();    
                        while (millisn<millis+20){
                            millisn=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }    
                    e.setColor(Color.white);
                    e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2);
                    e.setColor(Color.red);
                    moveLeft();
                    e.drawOval(x1,y1,x2,y2); 
         }}
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because the applet doesn't have keyboard focus. Also, don't forget to call super.paint

Comment: But I did set the focusable to "true"

Comment: That just means that the applet CAN receive keyboard focus, not that it has keyboard focus

Comment: then how do I add keyboard focus?

Comment: Normally, you would call requestFocusInWindow, but this might not work as expected in apllets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, most likely, the applet doesn't have keyboard focus. This is a common issue with KeyListener.

While you have set the applet as being focusable, it doesn't mean that the applet has keyboard focus.

You could try using `requestFocusInWindow`, but this may not work as expected in applets. You could also add a MouseListener to the applet, so that when the user clicks on the applet, you would `requestFocusInWindow` to ensure that the applet has keyboard focus

I would recommend, instead, if you have to develop an applet, you try using `JApplet`.  Instead of painting directly to the applet itself, I'd recommend that you use a custom component, say something like, `JPanel`, and override its `paintComponent` method instead.

Apart from providing flexibility in regards to the deployment of the component, it's also double buffered.

Don't forget to call `super.paintXxx`

Also, this would also allow you to use the key bindings API which has the ability to overcome many of the shot comings of the `KeyListener`

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your last line about super.paintXxx

Comment: If you override paint, you must call super.paint, if you override paintComponent, you must call super.paintComponent...